# Prove that for each odd $m> 2$, is true that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k \equiv 0 \pmod m$

Tags: congruences

please, know somebody solution for this argument?

Prove, that for each odd $m > 2$, it is true that $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k \equiv 0 \pmod m$$

Thanks for yours answers!

Comment: Hint: Try induction.

Comment: Where does $n$ appear in the equation?

Comment: EDITOR: I'm not sure if this is what you intend. The original phrasing was "Prove, that for each odd modulus m > 2, is true that sum from k=1 to m-1 k ≡ 0 (mod m)".

Comment: What is the modulus of the congruence, what role does $n$ play ? Please edit.

Comment: I think I edited this as the OP intended. I forgot to edit the title though.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k = \frac{(m-1)m}{2}$$

Note that if $m$ is odd, then $m-1$ is an even integer, which means we can write $\frac{(m-1)m}{2} = am$ for some integer $a$. And $am \equiv 0 \bmod{m}$ by inspection.

Comment: Why we need divided by 2?

Comment: @Dr.Zoidberg The $2$ is "absorbed" by the $m-1$ term. For instance, if $m=5$, we know $m-1 = 4$, and $4$ is divisible by $2$. So the $(m-1)/2$ part can be replaced by an integer $a$.